# how to filter data in array loop

Tags: javascript, object-literal

In my array is like this,

```
var myColumnDefs = [

    {a: "hh", b: "hh", c: "jk", d: "ggh", e: "hvh"},

    {a: "dd", b: "gg", d: "nn", e: "rr", f: "jj"},.....
]
```

I want to filter data and insert data in new array like this

```
var newarray = {a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

& another array

```
var mysecondarray = [

                {hh,hhjk,ggh,hvh},

                {dd,gg,nm,rr,jj},....
]
```

Comment: `{hh,hhjk,ggh,hvh},` is neither valid array not valid json

Comment: please clarify exactly what you need, and provide a more realistic and valid example. otherwise you will get downvoted :s

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** and do something like this

```js
var myColumnDefs = [
  {
    a: "hh",
    b: "hh",
    c: "jk",
    d: "ggh",
    e: "hvh"
  },

  {
    a: "dd",
    b: "gg",
    d: "nn",
    e: "rr",
    f: "jj"
  }
];

var arr1 = [],
  arr2 = [];

// iterate over `myColumnDefs` array and generate value array
arr2 = myColumnDefs.map(function(v, i) {
  // get keys from object
  var keys = Object.keys(v);
  // iterate over key values and generate the value array and then return
  return keys.map(function(k) {
    // check key value is in `arr1`, push if not
    if (arr1.indexOf(k) == -1)
      arr1.push(k);
    // return corresponding value based on key
    return v[k];
  });
});

document.write('First Array : <pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr1, null, 3) + '</pre> Second Array : <pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr2, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the result in arrays, then this should work. The result is in an object for further processing.

```js
var myColumnDefs = [{ a: "hh", b: "hh", c: "jk", d: "ggh", e: "hvh" }, { a: "dd", b: "gg", d: "nn", e: "rr", f: "jj" }],
    result = function (array) {
        var r = { keys: [], data: [] };
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            r.data.push(Object.keys(a).map(function (k) {
                !~r.keys.indexOf(k) && r.keys.push(k);
                return a[k];
            }));
        });
        return r;
    }(myColumnDefs);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that mysecondarray is having an array of array of values in the same order.

try

```
var columns = {}; //newarray 
var values = []; //mysecondarray 
myColumnDefs.forEach(function(value){

   var arr = [];
   for (var key in value)
   {
      columns[key] = true;
      arr.push(value[key]);
   }
   values.push(arr);

})
console.log("columns are " + JSON.stringify(Object(columns).keys, 0, 4));
console.log("values are " + JSON.stringify(values, 0, 4));
```