# how to filter data in array loop 222

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Previously I asked this question, ([how to filter data in array loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005897/how-to-filter-data-in-array-loop)) but I have some changes in my second array,.. as given below..
In my array is like this,

```
var myColumnDefs = [

    {a: "hh", b: "hh", c: "jk", d: "ggh", e: "hvh"},

    {a: "dd", b: "gg", d: "nn", e: "rr", f: "jj"},.....
]
```

I want to filter data and insert data in new array like this

```
var newarray = {a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

& another array

```
var mysecondarray = [

  {hh,hhjk,ggh,hvh,null},

  {dd,gg,null,nm,rr,jj},....
]
```

Comment: where do you specify the order?

Comment: It would help if you actually explain the rules how you want this data to be formed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First collect every key, then collect the data.

```js
var myColumnDefs = [{ a: "hh", c: "jk", d: "ggh", e: "hvh" }, { a: "dd", b: "gg", d: "nn", e: "rr", f: "jj" }],
    result = function (array) {
        var r = { keys: [], data: [] }, o = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
                if (!(k in o)) {
                    o[k] = r.keys.push(k) - 1;
                }
            });
        });
        r.keys.sort(); // sort all keys
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            r.data.push(r.keys.map(function (k) {
                return a[k];
            }));
        });
        return r;
    }(myColumnDefs);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: There is only one array no,.. but I want to two arrays,.. var newarray = {a,b,c,d,e,f} and var mysecondarray = [

  {hh,hhjk,ggh,hvh,null},

  {dd,gg,null,nm,rr,jj},....
]

Comment: in `result.data` you have two arrays as result.

Comment: @W.PraneethMadusanka, Note, that you can not compound object in this way `{hh,hhjk,ggh,hvh,null}`. If you want two separate arrays - use Nina's `result` object's parts: `var keys_arr = result['keys']; var new_arr = result['data']`;